# How can I pass a variable through an onclick event when javascript is creating the html?

Tags: javascript, onclick

My javascript creates a line of html.

That html has an onclick event call to `openSingle()`.

I need to pass a variable into that function.

`onclick="openSingle('+findID+')"`

When I check the dev panel when it runs, i get

`onclick="openSingle(WP0100200-3a)"`

The only thing that is missing is the quotes around the `id`.
But if i try to code in the quotes, it breaks the html and then puts everything out of order.

Here is my line of code and all the pertaining variables.

```
var iconImage = '<img src="../../resources/images/annotation-icon.png" style="float:left; margin-left:20px; margin-right:0px;"onclick="openSingle('+findID+')"/>';
var paragraph = '<p id="Manual-para" class="colorMe"><a href="';
var redirect = linkMe + '#' + findID;
var manName = section.childNodes( x ).getAttribute( "manualName" );
var workPack = section.childNodes( x ).getAttribute( "workPacket" );

document.getElementById( "annotateBody" ).innerHTML += iconImage + paragraph + redirect + '">' + annotationTitle + ' - ' + manName + ' - ' + workPack + '</a></p>';
```

Comment: Instead of writing HTML in javascript you should do `.createElement()`. Also please don't use inline JS in your HTML.

Comment: If you want quotes around the id, try escaping the single quotes using backslash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape quotes with a backslash like so

```
var iconImage = '<img src="../../resources/images/annotation-icon.png" style="float:left; margin-left:20px; margin-right:0px;"onclick="openSingle(\''+findID+'\')"/>';
```

and as other comments suggested you should ideally avoid inline Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Escape the single quotes, like this:

```
var iconImage = '<img src="../../resources/images/annotation-icon.png" style="float:left; margin-left:20px; margin-right:0px;"onclick="openSingle(\''+findID+'\')"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `\'` will fix the problem

```
var iconImage = '<img src="../../resources/images/annotation-icon.png" style="float:left; margin-left:20px; margin-right:0px;"onclick="openSingle(\''+findID+'\;)"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: with escaping character \ for ' character

```
var iconImage = '<img src="../../resources/images/annotation-icon.png" style="float:left; margin-left:20px; margin-right:0px;"onclick="openSingle(\''+findID+'\;)"/>';
```

Also try concating `&lsquo;`and`&rsquo;`

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could try doing is attach the onclick after you create the DOM node. This lets you be as flexible as you want and avoids having to eval strings and other things like that.

```
var domnode = /* get the image tag */
domnode.onclick = function(){ openSingle(findId) }
```