# How can I send two parameters with a HTML onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have this event that sends the ID parameter to a function that generates a URL, but I want to send two parameters instead of just the ID. I'd like to send the name also.

With this code I can only send one parameter, but I need to send two.
Based on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13585280/1575353) where one parameter is passed, I tried the following:

```
 '<li id="link4"><a href="#" onclick="generateURL(\'' + jsonObject.id + '\');">Line</a></li>'
```

This is the method that generates my URL

```
function generateURL(id, name)
{
    window.location.href = 'https://www.example'+ id + name + '.com';
 }
```

In other words I'm trying to imitate this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="generateURL(jsonObject.id, jsonObject.name)></a>
```

And if I try this:

```
'<li id="link4"><a href="#" onclick="generateURL(\'' + jsonObject.id + ',' + jsonObject.name + '\');">Line Name</a></li>'
```

This happens:

[image: Not receiving the NAME parameter]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two arguments are being strung together into one single string literal - so if you inspect that element or find it in the source, it should look like below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="generateURL('1337,testName');">Line Name</a>
```

One solution is to add escaped single-quotes (i.e. `\'`) before and after the comma:

```
'<li id="link4"><a href="#" onclick="generateURL(\'' + jsonObject.id + '\',\'' + jsonObject.name + '\');">Line Name</a></li>';
```

Observe the difference between the link in the 1<sup>st</sup> list and the link in the 2<sup>nd</sup> list in the example below:

```js
var jsonObject = {
  name: 'testName',
  id: 1337
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var liHTML = '<li id="link4"><a href="#" onclick="generateURL(\'' + jsonObject.id + ',' + jsonObject.name + '\');">Line Name</a></li>';
  document.getElementById('theList').innerHTML = liHTML;
  liHTML = '<li id="link5"><a href="#" onclick="generateURL(\'' + jsonObject.id + '\',\'' + jsonObject.name + '\');">Line Name</a></li>';
  document.getElementById('theOtherList').innerHTML = liHTML;
});

function generateURL(id, name) {
  console.log('generateURL() - id: ', id, 'name: ', name);
}
```

```html
1<sup>st</sup>List: <ul id="theList"></ul>
2<sup>nd</sup>List: <ul id="theOtherList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in one continuous string as the first argument, `id`, into generateURL(id, name), instead of passing two individual arguments, `id` and `name`. In other words, these are the arguments you use:

`id:`  `\'' + jsonObject.ln_org_code + ',' + jsonObject.ln_name + '\'`

`name:`   (hence why `name` is undefined in your screenshot)

To fix this, simply remove the quotes from the comma between your two arguments. This comma separates `id` and `name`, and will register `jsonObject.ln_org_code` as the id and `jsonObject.ln_name` as the name. Additionally, be careful with the tick mark placement on your first forward slash. Personally, I would not concatenate the strings until the function call.

In other words, here is how your function call should look.

`<li id="link4"><a href="#" onclick="generateURL(('\' + jsonObject.ln_org_code), (jsonObject.ln_name + '\'));">Arranque de Linea</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes from the comma between your two arguments. This comma separates id and name, and will register `jsonObject.ln_org_code` as the id and `jsonObject.ln_name` as the name. Additionally, be careful with the tick mark placement on your first forward slash. Personally, I would not concatenate the strings until the function call.

Here is how your function call should look.

```
<li id="link4"><a href="#" onclick="generateURL(('\' + jsonObject.ln_org_code), (jsonObject.ln_name + '\'));">Arranque de Linea</a></li>
```