# Passing two perameters in onclick event?

Tags: javascript

I have this button and want to pass two perameter in onclick event.

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info"onclick=updatebook(${bm[i].id},${bm[i].description})>Update</button>`

After my attempt I got this error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
```

Comment: It seems that your button attribute is working good. There is an error in '${bm[i].id},${bm[i].description}' . I recommend you to print this ${bm[i].id},${bm[i].description} on webpage for double sure.

Comment: You can pass parameters as variables by using '\' syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074876/how-can-i-send-two-parameters-with-a-html-onclick-event

Answer (score 2):

If you want the arguments to be string literals you are missing the quotes, and also you might be missing the double quotes wrapping the function itself:

```
onclick="updatebook(`${bm[i].id}`,`${bm[i].description}`)"
```

Comment: thank you but my onclick is also in template literals

Comment: Do you mean the code you pasted is the template literal as a whole? In that case would you not still be missing the double quotes?

`\`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info "onclick="updatebook(${bm[i].id},${bm[i].description})">Update</button>\``

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what your data looks like so I assumed it looks something like this:

```
const bm = [
    { "id": 1, "description": "this is bm1" },
    { "id": 2, "description": "this is bm2" }
];
```

Then I wrapped the `onclick` attribute value in double quotes `""` and the second parameter  of the `updatebook` function in single quotes. This worked for me without the error.

```
for (let i = 0; i < bm.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('elementID').innerHTML += `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="updatebook(${bm[i].id},'${bm[i].description}')">Update</button>`;
}
```